# How to write the following sql query with CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have problem while I want to write query into Criteria Builder. Or if is better to compose SQL query to be easyer to write in criteria builder ?

```
select
    DATA_TABLE.*, M_ORDER.CODE 
from
    ( select
        log0_.MSG_ID,
        login1_.NAME,
        log0_.METHOD,
        logpa2_.VALUE
    from
        M_LOG log0_
    inner join
        M_LOG_INTER login1_ 
            on log0_.ID_INTER=login1_.ID_INTER 
    inner join
        M_PARAMS logpa2_ 
            on log0_.MS_ID=logpa2_.MS_ID 
    where
        logpa2_.KEY='id'
    ) DATA_TABLE, M_ORDER
WHERE
    data.value = m_order.ID and
    rownum <= 10;
```

Comment: I would use something like QueryDSL instead of CriteriaBuilder. I think in that type of query, CriteriaBuilder will be too complex, and when using other Entities in the subquery, Hibernate will have some complaints over entities not being known in the context (even if you use Join or Subquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructured (simplified) SQL query:

```
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        log0_.MSG_ID,
        login1_.NAME,
        order3_.CODE,
        log0_.METHOD
        logpa2_.VALUE,
    from
        M_LOG log0_,
        M_LOG_INTER login1_,
        M_LOG_PARAMS logpa2_,
        M_ORDER order3_ 
    where
        logpa2_.KEY='id' 
        and logpa2_.VALUE=order3_.ID 
        and log0_.MS_ID=logpa2_.MS_ID 
        and log0_.ID_INTER=login1_.ID_INTER
    ) 
where
    rownum <= 10;
```

And query with CriteriaBuilder was easly.